# GPO - How to prevent popup while loading a IE plugin (for Skype for Business WebApp)?

Tags: group-policy, skype-for-business-2016, activex, skype-for-business-online

I trying to simplify to the maximum all user alerts related to ActiveX/Plugins needed for Skype for Business Web-App to work ( it is an On-prem Skype for business installation).

What I did so far is:

- Configure the website FQDN (entrypoint) as trusted site (value 2).

  Windows Components/Internet Explorer/Internet Control Panel/Security
  Page/Site to Zone Assignment List/
- Enable the execution of all ActiveX

Windows Components/Internet Explorer/Internet Control Panel/Security Page/Trusted Sites Zone\ **Run ActiveX controls and plugins**, set to Enable

- The plugin that is trying to load seems to be in the same domain but just in case I also set

Windows Components/Internet Explorer/Internet Control Panel/Security Page/Trusted Sites Zone\ **Allow only approved domains to use ActiveX controls without prompt**  , set to Enable -> Disable.

But still, when the Skype webapp is launched, I keep receiving the following popup.

Any idea how to get rid of it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution after using the tool Zsof Uninstaller 
http://www.zsoft.dk/
to trace all the action performed by the MSI.

Some entries called my attention
REG ADDED!      HKU S-1-5-21-2739979431-3630490944-714476731-53848\Software\Microsoft\SkypeForBusinessPlugin\15.8\AllowedDomains

and I also found in google some instructions for Lync, the previous name of the same webapp.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/trouble-installing-the-plug-in-3dba99b4-0f57-4ed7-9d70-682188c53404?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#__toc378335123

so basically I just needed to create a registry entry via GPO with the FQDN mentioned in the popup.
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SkypeForBusinessPlugin\15.8\AllowedDomains

After that, popup will no appear anymore.